# How I can create migration for SQL queries in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity framework 6 code 1st.

I have couple SQL queried as follows:

```
delete from [dbo].[User];


 insert into [dbo].[User] (id, permission_id)
 values (1, (select [id] from [permission] where [name] = 'write')),
       (......
```

I need to Add Migration for these Scripts, How I can create migration for SQL queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the ef core tools ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet))

```cs
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

issue a command from the cli to create a migration ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli))

```cs
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

You will also need to have a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` in the startup project.

In a lot of my work I have a web assembly (api) and a separate model/repository assembly, so a typical migration command for me looks like

```cs
dotnet ef migrations add MigraitonName -s StartupProject -p RepositoryProejct -c DbContext
```

Once you have a migration you can run the following command to update your database

```cs
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: when I run "add-migration myScripts" it will create a migration, that has up and Down method, where should I copy the scripts?